# How does Longarm affect which squares are threatened?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Longarm's description reads:

> Your arms temporarily grow in length, increasing your reach with those limbs by 5 feet.

My DM tells me that, I no longer threaten the squares around me due to this extension. It seems ridiculous that I could not bend my elbows  to reach creatures next to me.

Other questions about this spell seem to involve other reach enhancing effects that are not relevant and may interfere with the final answer.

When this spell is cast, can I hit creatures one square away as well as two squares away? Or am I only able to hit creatures two squares away?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like the GM wants the spell [*long arm*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/long-arm/) to apply to your PC's limbs the weapon quality [reach](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/#wpn-quality-reach) rather than increasing your PC's [natural reach](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/) to like that of the typical creature that possesses the size category Large (tall).

While the GM is free to rule any way he wants, the spell *long arm* simply says, "Your arms temporarily grow in length, increasing your reach with those limbs by 5 feet." The spell does *not* say, "Your arms temporarily grow in length so that weapons you wield with them that lack the weapon quality reach gain the weapon quality reach"—this would not only be extremely complicated but also little strange: I mean, generally, if *that* were the effect you wanted, you'd just wield (or even draw!) a weapon that had the weapon quality reach instead!

Convincing the GM that the spell *long arm* actually means natural reach may be difficult because the game has two entirely different definitions of *reach*, one for weapons that are particularly long and don't usually threaten adjacent squares, and another for a creature's natural reach that allows it to threaten *all* the squares around it. I urge showing the GM the diagram linked to above for a Large (tall) creature then [this *Order of the Stick* comic strip](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0012.html), and, if those fail, having your PC (armed with a non-reach weapon) get all up in every ogre's grill—where, if the DM's consistent, your PC should be totally safe—until the GM changes his mind.

Answer (score 5):

The term here is reach, and not as it applies to weapons, but arms.

Your dm would be correct if this was added to a reach weapon. But natural reach is a little bit different. This is treated as if you had increased a size category (as large, not long), which allows you to attack adjacent squares and out according to your reach.

Now, the main reason why it is natural reach, is because it affects all your attacks, not just those made with a weapon. It allows you to have a large area with touch spells as well.

You can find a useful natural [reach table here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates).